# Express restart matching route - Redirect

Tags: javascript, http, express

I want to change url address during processing request. Implementation of simple redirect.
How can I change the current url and restart processing of the route matching in express?

For instance I would like to have something like this:

```
app.get "/r/*",  (req, res, next) ->
   changeURL = "/myverylongurl/param1....."
   next(...)
```

and somewherein the code handler for route /myverylongurl/....

```
app.get "/myverylongurl/*",  (req, res, next) ->
    # complex thing here
```

So when someone request http://myserverfake111.com/r/param1 the system actually ends up processing block "# complex thing here".

Answer (score 0):

Use `req.session` to keep track of objects across redirects. Your question isn't clear what the redirect does, but if you don't need to save anything you can skip req.session and simply do `res.redirect("/myverylongurl/param1.....")` from inside the request handler function of `/r/*`.

```
var http = require('http')
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();

app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.cookieParser('asdf 0a98234ja       af anekjoavzcx'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/'
,function(req, res){ 
  res.send(200, 'Hi, /') 
});

app.get("/r/*"
,function(req, res, next){
  //res.redirect('/myverylongurl?param1=true');
  req.session.changeURL = "/myverylongurl?param1=true";
  next();
},function(req, res, next){
  res.redirect('/foobar');
});

app.get('/foobar', function(req, res){
  var destination = req.session.changeURL || "/";
  if(req.session.changeURL){ delete req.session.changeURL };
  res.redirect(destination);
});

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I need to make internal redirection without exploiting client. In this case you send 301 http request to the client, what's not what I need.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to execute code that is inside one Express route handler from inside another Express route handler, without a 301 redirect to call that route. You should probably instead move `#complex code here` into its own function and call that function from both `/r/*` and `/myverylongurl?param1=true' handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking to process two routes with the same code. If you don't want to use a 301 redirect with `res.redirect`, consider organizing your code so you separate the shared logic and execute it for both routes. You can still use `req.session` to maintain variable scope along an internal handler function chain, even if it doesn't send a redirect. Or, you may be able to place the complex code in its own function with a callback and execute it on demand.

```
var http = require('http')
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();

app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.cookieParser('asdf 0a98234ja       af anekjoavzcx'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/' ,function(req, res){ res.send(200, 'Hi, /') });

// strategy 1
function complexThings1(req, res, next){
  console.log('#complex stuff started')
  process.nextTick(function(){ // example asynchronous function
    req.session.complexOutput="2i+3";
    console.log('#complex stuff finished')
    next();
  });
};

app.get('/myverylongurl'
,complexThings1
,function(req, res){
  res.send(200, 'complex things 1 output: '+req.session.complexOutput);
});

app.get("/r/*"
,complexThings1
,function(req, res){
  res.send(200, 'complex things 1 output: '+req.session.complexOutput);
});

// strategy 2
function complexThings2(input, callback){
  console.log('#complex stuff finished');
  process.nextTick(function(){ // example asynchronous function
    console.log('#complex stuff finished');
    var output = input
    callback(null, output);
  });
};

app.get('/s/*', function(req, res){
  complexThings2('8i+3.14', function(err, output){
    res.send(200, 'complex things 2 output: '+output);
  });
});

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Sure I know, that's obvious. But I'm looking for a solution which to avoid that.